# Getting Satinizer warning when calling sanitizer.sanitize

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a `component` that gets some string from a service, this `service` loads its strings from a `json`.

Since this json can be altered by an attacker (connecting to the server etc) I want the string to be sanitized before being shown in order to avoid XSS flaws.

Problem is that I get an annoying `log` message:

> WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).

Everytime I search for a way to remove this message, I find someone who says "bypass the sanitizer" but this is actually not what I want to do, I need the sanitizer to do its job.

I wrote a simple example running on this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/hFCY5eJAQaDK0VogfzQP?p=preview):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div [innerHTML]="text">
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  text:string;
  constructor(sanitizer:DomSanitizer) {
    this.text = sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML,"<script>window.alert('XSS')</script>");
  }
}
```

I am using `[innerHTML]` binding because I need things like `<b>hello</b>` to be rendered as **hello**.

Comment: If I remember correctly, warning message appears only in developement mode, not in production, so you should have no concerns.

Comment: but even in dev mode it's kind of boring, because this component is used everywhere in every template (it's an i18n component, used for every string shown in our templates).

Comment: I don't think you can suppress that message without editing `html_sanitizer.ts` file itself: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/platform-browser/src/security/html_sanitizer.ts That's where the warning message is generated. Line: `DOM.log('WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).');`